# How do I find individual values of $\sin(\varphi)$ and $\cos(\varphi)$ from $x = a\sin^{2}(\varphi) + b\cos^{2}(\varphi)$?

Tags: trigonometry, substitution

If $x = a\sin^2\phi+ b\cos^2\phi$, express $\sin$ and $\cos$ in terms of $x$ ( $a$ and $b$ are real constants)

I know how to find values of $T$ ratios in equations like $x = a\sin^2t$ or $x = b\cos^2t$ but how do I find the values of $\sin(t)$ and $\cos(t)$
in expressions like $x = \sin^2t + 5\cos^2t$ or $x = a\sin t + b\cos t$?

Comment: Write $\cos^2 = 1-\sin^2$, solve for sin, then for cos.

Answer (score 3):

**HINT**

I would recommend you to proceed as follows:

\begin{align*}
x & = a\sin^{2}(\varphi) + b\cos^{2}(\varphi)\\\\
& = (a\sin^{2}(\varphi) + a\cos^{2}(\varphi)) + (b - a)\cos^{2}(\varphi)\\\\
& = a + (b - a)\cos^{2}(\varphi)
\end{align*}

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yes, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

**1.** $$x=a\sin^2\phi + b\cos^2\phi$$

**2.** $$x=a\sin^2\phi+b-b\sin^2\phi$$

**3.** $$x=b+(a-b)\sin^2\phi$$

**4.** $$\sin\phi=\pm\sqrt\frac{x-b}{a-b}$$

$$\cos\phi=\pm\sqrt\frac{a-x}{a-b}$$

**Hope this helps!!**